# Generic class to hold derived type

Tags: java, generics

I have got started with Java Generics. in the below class, as the class is holding T, I want to have also a class which can extend T. Please help.

```
public class HolderUnique<T> {

     private T a;

     public HolderUnique(T a){
         this.a = a;
     }
     public T getA() {
         return a;
     }
     public void setA(T a) {
         this.a = a;
    }
 }
```

Comment: You can already do that. Try it out. You can assign a subtype of `T` to `T`.

Comment: You can use a subclass of T with no problem

Comment: But How can I do that?

Comment: `HolderUnique<Object> h = new HolderUnique<>(new Object()); h.setA("hello");h.setA(Integer.valueOf(23));`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a class S, which extends T, and you have also declared `hold` as a `HolderUnique<T>`. Let's also say you have declared sObj as type S. There is absolutely no reason why you cannot say `T.setA(sObj)`.